# How do I return 'null' if the array is empty rather than undefined using the .find method with arrow functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions, arrow-functions

I have a function that takes an array of people objects and returns the first found object from the particular array.  In this case - 'isDoctor'.

```
const doctors = [ 
      { name: "`Jack Jones`", isDoctor: false},
      { name: "John Smith", isDoctor: true},
      { name: "Louise Young", isDoctor: false},
      { name: "David Boyle", isDoctor: true},
      { name: "Lisa Carr", isDoctor: false },
     ];


function findFirstDoctor(people) {
return people.find(person => person.isDoctor === true)
}
```

The code I have written correctly returns the below; however in a scenario where there is an empty array or when all 'isDoctor' is false; how would I return 'null' rather than undefined?

```
Object {
  isDoctor: true,
  name: "John Smith"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to use `.find` for this, you would have to explicitly assign or return `null` yourself, if nothing was found:

```js
const doctors = [ 
];

function findFirstDoctor(people) {
  const foundDoctor = people.find(person => person.isDoctor === true)
  return foundDoctor || null;
}

console.log(findFirstDoctor(doctors));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `||` to provide a specific "falsy" value:

```
function findFirstDoctor(people) {
  return people.find(person => person.isDoctor === true) || null;
}
```

(Also: I would advise against testing explicitly with `===` to `true` unless you *really* need to because of your data model. If `.isDoctor` is intended to be a boolean flag, then all you really need is `person => person.isDoctor`.)

Anyway adding `|| null` to the end takes advantage of the fact that `.find()` will return an object if it does find something, and that's never "falsy".  Thus the only way the code on the far side of `||` is evaluated is when `.find()` returns `undefined`, so you can substitute `null`.

Personally I think that distinguishing between `null` and `undefined` in most circumstances is just another fragile coding practice. The `==` and `!=` operators, when comparing to either `null` or `undefined`, always treat both as equivalent.